# jquery .val() strange behavior on dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a html `<select>` tag with some `<option>`s. Something like this:

```
<select id="season">
    <option value="">Select an option</option>
    <option value="1">Spring</option>
    <option value="2">Summer</option>
    <option value="3">Autumn</option>
    <option value="4">Winter</option>
</select>
```

And I have this javascript code:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#season").val("1");
   });
</script>
```

This does not select "Spring" option and remain in "Select an option" option! But when I use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       setTimeout(function(){
           $("#season").val("1");
       }, 100)
   });
```

This works correct! What is the problem? Any help would be greatly appreciate.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rfroymx2/1/ - looks fine

Comment: Is the `<select>` and/or it's `<option>`s written out dynamically on page load?

Comment: Add `console. log('select', $("#season").length)` just before setting the value in version 1 and check

Comment: @JamesThorpe No matter. I tested both. First I filled options from my server(java with jstl tag) and second I wrote static value.

Comment: You fill options using asynchronous call? Then you have to add it in success.

Comment: @AlexChar I fill options on page load.

Comment: Yes but how? Using an ajax call I suppose?

Comment: No, I'm using jstl tag with java list. Also I tried static options, but not worked.

Comment: @hamed Removed comment and put it as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("option[value='1']").attr('selected','selected');
});
</script>
```

Above mention code will work.

even below mention your code will work, but script section should below all the HTML code and before the body close tag. Because once jQuery or javaScript start executing at that time HTML DOM will available and script can able to select that DOM.

```
<script>
 $("#season").val("1");
</script>
```

In your code once you add `setTimeout` and your script is able to select the option because you are delaying by 100 micro second, it means before executing your script HTML DOM are available that is why you are able to select the DOM

```
<script>
 setTimeout(function(){
  $("#season").val("1");
 }, 100)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

on page load is called after all resources is loaded whereas jquery ready is called when dom is loaded so basically ready gets called before on-load. Hence it does not work